# Apply exclusionary criteria for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have some VBA code that will apply an advanced/autofilter to exclude three variables in particular. For instance, `In this entire data set, hide entries for which Column A has values X, Y, or Z.

This code works for inclusions as far as I can tell

```
Sheets(sheetName).Range("$A:$" & finalCol).AutoFilter Field:=fieldIndex, criteria1:=Array("=" & crit1, "=" & crit2, "=" & crit3), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But this does not work for exclusions:

```
Sheets(sheetName).Range("$A:$" & finalCol).AutoFilter Field:=fieldIndex, criteria1:=Array("<>" & crit1, "<>" & crit2, "<>" & crit3), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Data validation code

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range(Cells(10, 2).Validation.Formula1)

For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1) 
    For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2) 
        Debug.Print Arr(R, C)
    Next C
Next R
```

Is there a way to make this array "one dimensional" like in the answer?

Comment: So where are you stuck? Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I deleted my code already because it didn't work. There's a field called "criteria1" that lets you add your own criteria, but it only allows up to 2. You can, however, use an array, but this only seems to work for inclusions. I can't get it to work for exclusions.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Scratch that, I still had a copy. Added code.

Comment: The only operator that does work with multiple conditions in an filter is the `=` equals. If you want to filter everything else BUT the 3 criterias you need to construct an array with all OTHER criteria. Simply, create an array of everything and remove the 3 criteria you do not want to see.

Comment: @mehow Is there a way to take a cell's "data validation" fields and stuff it all into an array, and then exclude three values?

Comment: One moment posting an answer... post testing it

Comment: Actually I am not sure if I can accomplish any of this because now that I think of it, a few of my values sometimes contain values like "<10" which is why I had to use the "=" & modification in the array (so it doesn't interpret the < as an operator). I don't know if this is automatically taken care of though in an already-allocated array vs. explicitly delineating the terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

**LOGIC:**

What we are doing is creating the array of values that we want and then passing that array to the autofilter.

**CODE:**

Try this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Ar() As String, itm
    Dim Lrow As Long, n As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim TempAr
    Dim ExclusionList As String
    Dim doNotAdd As Boolean

    '~~> Exclusion List
    ExclusionList = "X,Y,Z"

    TempAr = Split(ExclusionList, ",")

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)

        '~~> Get unique collection of items
        For i = 2 To Lrow
            On Error Resume Next
            Col.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, CStr(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i

        '~~> Create an array which doesn't have the items that we don't need
        For Each itm In Col
            For i = LBound(TempAr) To UBound(TempAr)
                If itm = TempAr(i) Then
                    doNotAdd = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If doNotAdd = False Then
                ReDim Preserve Ar(n)
                Ar(n) = itm
                n = n + 1
            End If

            doNotAdd = False
        Next

        '~~> Autofilter
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Ar(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Does this code with with, instead of X, something like "<10"?

Comment: The logic remains the same. Instead of predefining your list like I did, when you loop through the collection, check if the value is <10 or not and then add it to the array :)

Comment: I am not sure if I can use this (I am not a programmer by any means), my full list of values is referenced through a data validation. So my "full" list is located via "Cells(10,2).Validation.Formula1" which if you print it out, shows "'Other Sheet'$B$4:$AG$4" for a range reference. Can I somehow take this and put it in the array instead? (I believe Ar() in your code?)

Comment: `I am not sure if I can use this (I am not a programmer by any means)` I can answer your question but I want you to try it first. understand what the code does. If you are still stuck then post the code that you tried and the error that you are getting and then we will take it form there :)

Comment: I understand what your code is doing, but I don't know how to parse a full list from data validation range reference to the Ar() array

Comment: Okay I got some code that'll do it but it's not one-dimensional, I added what I mean to the OP

Comment: `Is there a way to make this array "one dimensional" like in the answer?` Transpose the array.

Comment: I don't know what that means but I figured out another strategy anyway using a second array a Redim Preserve at each step.

Comment: Accepting this as answer anyway since it technically does answer the question as stated